# Bootstrap Container-fluid : Bottom Container not aligning Columns correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I correctly (Best practice) line up the bottom two text paragraphs to match others above with the relevant spacing between. Any pointers would be appreciated, its got to be something simple I've missed due to baby brain.

Every time I've got this issue:

> Bottom Container not aligning columns / rows / spacing correctly below info accordion.

Please see the [Demo URL](http://codeply.com/go/KeSDfZWbj2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the same types of column numbers. On top you use `col-md-7` and `col-md-4`, but on the bottom row you are using `col-md-6` and `col-md-6`. Obviously it won't line up. Either use 7 and 4 for both or use 6 and 6 for both.